# How to add multi level menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new on same. I have download AdminEx bootstrap theme from a site and I found the theme has no multi level menu. But I need the same. I have attached here sidebar HTML and JS script. Please help me to build this.

HTML Code [as on theme]:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked custom-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
    <li class="menu-list"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> <span>Layouts</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-list">
            <li><a href="blank_page.html"> Blank Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="boxed_view.html"> Boxed Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="leftmenu_collapsed_view.html"> Sidebar Collapsed</a></li>
            <li><a href="horizontal_menu.html"> Horizontal Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>UI Elements</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-list">
            <li><a href="general.html"> General</a></li>
            <li><a href="buttons.html"> Buttons</a></li>
            <li><a href="tabs-accordions.html"> Tabs &amp; Accordions</a></li>
            <li><a href="typography.html"> Typography</a></li>
            <li><a href="slider.html"> Slider</a></li>
            <li><a href="panels.html"> Panels</a></li>
            <li><a href="widgets.html"> Widgets</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want multi level with same collapsible effect, like :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked custom-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
    <li class="menu-list"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>UI Elements</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-list">
            <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Buttons</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Color Buttons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Image Buttons</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I try to find JS code in theme(script.js):

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    // custom scrollbar

    $("html").niceScroll({styler:"fb",cursorcolor:"#65cea7", cursorwidth: '6', cursorborderradius: '0px', background: '#424f63', spacebarenabled:false, cursorborder: '0',  zindex: '1000'});

    $(".left-side").niceScroll({styler:"fb",cursorcolor:"#65cea7", cursorwidth: '3', cursorborderradius: '0px', background: '#424f63', spacebarenabled:false, cursorborder: '0'});


    $(".left-side").getNiceScroll();
    if ($('body').hasClass('left-side-collapsed')) {
        $(".left-side").getNiceScroll().hide();
    }



    // Toggle Left Menu
   jQuery('.menu-list > a').click(function() {

      var parent = jQuery(this).parent();
      var sub = parent.find('> ul');

      if(!jQuery('body').hasClass('left-side-collapsed')) {
         if(sub.is(':visible')) {
            sub.slideUp(200, function(){
               parent.removeClass('nav-active');
               jQuery('.main-content').css({height: ''});
               mainContentHeightAdjust();
            });
         } else {
            visibleSubMenuClose();
            parent.addClass('nav-active');
            sub.slideDown(200, function(){
                mainContentHeightAdjust();
            });
         }
      }
      return false;
   });

   function visibleSubMenuClose() {
      jQuery('.menu-list').each(function() {
         var t = jQuery(this);
         if(t.hasClass('nav-active')) {
            t.find('> ul').slideUp(200, function(){
               t.removeClass('nav-active');
            });
         }
      });
   }

   function mainContentHeightAdjust() {
      // Adjust main content height
      var docHeight = jQuery(document).height();
      if(docHeight > jQuery('.main-content').height())
         jQuery('.main-content').height(docHeight);
   }

   //  class add mouse hover
   jQuery('.custom-nav > li').hover(function(){
      jQuery(this).addClass('nav-hover');
   }, function(){
      jQuery(this).removeClass('nav-hover');
   });


   // Menu Toggle
   jQuery('.toggle-btn').click(function(){
       $(".left-side").getNiceScroll().hide();

       if ($('body').hasClass('left-side-collapsed')) {
           $(".left-side").getNiceScroll().hide();
       }
      var body = jQuery('body');
      var bodyposition = body.css('position');

      if(bodyposition != 'relative') {

         if(!body.hasClass('left-side-collapsed')) {
            body.addClass('left-side-collapsed');
            jQuery('.custom-nav ul').attr('style','');

            jQuery(this).addClass('menu-collapsed');

         } else {
            body.removeClass('left-side-collapsed chat-view');
            jQuery('.custom-nav li.active ul').css({display: 'block'});

            jQuery(this).removeClass('menu-collapsed');

         }
      } else {

         if(body.hasClass('left-side-show'))
            body.removeClass('left-side-show');
         else
            body.addClass('left-side-show');

         mainContentHeightAdjust();
      }

   });


   searchform_reposition();

   jQuery(window).resize(function(){

      if(jQuery('body').css('position') == 'relative') {

         jQuery('body').removeClass('left-side-collapsed');

      } else {

         jQuery('body').css({left: '', marginRight: ''});
      }

      searchform_reposition();

   });

   function searchform_reposition() {
      if(jQuery('.searchform').css('position') == 'relative') {
         jQuery('.searchform').insertBefore('.left-side-inner .logged-user');
      } else {
         jQuery('.searchform').insertBefore('.menu-right');
      }
   }

    // panel collapsible
    $('.panel .tools .fa').click(function () {
        var el = $(this).parents(".panel").children(".panel-body");
        if ($(this).hasClass("fa-chevron-down")) {
            $(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
            el.slideUp(200);
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
            el.slideDown(200); }
    });

    $('.todo-check label').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('li').children('.todo-title').toggleClass('line-through');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.todo-remove', function () {
        $(this).closest("li").remove();
        return false;
    });

    $("#sortable-todo").sortable();


    // panel close
    $('.panel .tools .fa-times').click(function () {
        $(this).parents(".panel").parent().remove();
    });

    // tool tips

    $('.tooltips').tooltip();

    // popovers

    $('.popovers').popover();

})(jQuery);
```

Theme Live URL: http://themeforest.net/item/adminex-bootstrap-3-responsive-admin-template/7399319

I think it can possible through jquery.
Please help to build the same. Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes:

The `html` changes are just an example, of course you will change it according to your puporse.

***index.html***

**From**

```
<li><a href="blank_page.html"> Blank Page</a></li>
```

**To**

```
<li class="menu-list nav-active">
   <a href="">More options</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu-list">
        <li><a href="boxed_view.html">More option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="boxed_view.html">More option 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

***/js/scripts.js***

**From**

```
jQuery('.menu-list').each(function() {
   var t = jQuery(this);
     if(t.hasClass('nav-active')) {
        t.find('> ul').slideUp(200, function(){
           t.removeClass('nav-active');
        });
     }
});
```

**To**

```
elem.parent().siblings('.nav-active').find('> ul').slideUp(200, function(){
   t.removeClass('nav-active');
});
```

Comment: I want upto three level not two level. and also your JS script not working@ Mosh

Comment: now the menu is 2 level. I was added one more under blank page link. Also I downloaded the template and did the changes in my answer and it works. Are you sure that you did the changes correctly? Any errors in the `console`?

Comment: Lot's of thanks Mosh, its working fine, but when sidebar collapse I want to show third level menu on hover. check live url to understand,